# Rename, duplicate and remove files

Tags: visual-studio-code

I could rename, duplicate, and move files in **Atom Editor** easily
by change focus to Tree View and then

type "m" and "d"

How to perform such operations in **VScode**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

VScode does not support out of the box. But you can achieve by installing the extension [File Utils](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=sleistner.vscode-fileutils) - *A convenient way of creating, duplicating, moving, renaming, deleting files and directories*.

> Inspired by Sidebar Enhancements for Sublime.